# Proof verification: Every convex function on $(a,b)$ is continuous .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, continuity, proof-writing

> A real-valued function $f$ defined in $(a, b)$ is said to be convex if $f( tx+ (1 - t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1 - t)f(y)$
> whenever $a < x < b, a < y < b, 0 < t < 1$

I want to Prove that every convex function is continuous and I had an idea that can be used to prove this statement but my proof writing skills is not the best so I made a  "Proof idea" paragraph which gave an intuition (and better explanation than my proof ) of my idea and then the proof and the "n summary" paragraph gives the main points of the proof I hope this make my proof easier to follow.

This proof can be used to show that if $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\le\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ for all $x,y \in (a,b)$  and $f$ is bounded then $f$ continuous at $(a,b)$.

---

### Proof idea

If $|x-c | < \delta$, then $x-\delta< c <x +\delta $
, $\exists  0<|h|< \delta $ such that we can write $ c+ h = x$. If I could prove that $|f(c) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$  or $|f(c+h) - f(c)| < \varepsilon  $  this will be enough to prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$.
**I will write $x$ as $c+h$**
where $|h|<\delta $
and I noticed that $f(x)- f(c)=f(c+h)−f(c)\leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}(f(c+2h)−f(c))$

> this inequality is true because $f$ is convex i.e $f(c+h)= f\left(\frac 1 2 (c+2h)+(\frac{1}{2})c\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}f(c+2h) + \frac{1}{2}f(c)$ and subtracting $f(c)$ from both sides gives this inequality.

here I noticed that I can decrease the factor in red as much as I want, in other words $f(c+2^kh)−f(c)≤\frac{1}{2}(f(c+2^{k+1}h)−f(c))$
which made me conclude that $f(c+h)−f(c)\le \frac{1}{2^n}(f(c+2^nh)−f(c))$
this is the main idea but it is missing 3 thing:

- To prove that $f$ is bounded in some closed interval around $c$
  so that I can make use of $f(c+h)−f(c)\leq \frac{1}{2^n}(f(c+2^nh)−f(c))$ i.e the $f(c+2^nh)−f(c)$ is bounded
- To make sure to choose $\delta$ small enough st $c\pm 2^n \delta \in$ the closed interval the f is bounded on ,and since $|h| < \delta$, $ c+ 2^n h \in$ the closed interval the $f$ is bounded on, this will conclude that $f(x)- f(c) < \frac{1}{2^n}(f(c+2^nh)−f(c))$ and I can choose $n $  big enough st  $ \frac{1}{2^n}(|f(c+2^nh)|+|f(c)|) < \varepsilon $
- It will remain to prove that $f(c) - f(c+h) < \varepsilon $  wich will be concluded with a very similar inequality $f(c) - f(c+h ) \leq \frac{1}{2^n} (f(c-(2^n-1) h) - f(c+h))$

**In summary** the proof can be divided into

- if $|x-c|< \delta$ we can write $x=c+h$ for some $|h|<\delta$
- Since $(a,b )$ is open and $c \in (a,b ) $ then there exist $y>0$ such that $[c-y,c+y] \subset (a,b ) $
- Proving $f$ is bounded on $[c-y,c+y]$ and letting $M:=2 \sup{|f(x)|}$
- For all $\varepsilon >0$ choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{M}{2^n}<\varepsilon$ let $\delta= \frac{y}{2^{n+1}} $
- Proving by the definition of convexity  that $f(c+h) - f(c) \le \frac{1}{2} (f(c+2h) - f(c) )\leq \frac{1}{4} (f(c+4h) - f(c) ) \leq \dots \leq  \frac{1}{2^n} (f(c+2^nh) - f(c) )  \le \frac{M}{2^n} <\varepsilon $.
- Proving by the definition of convexity  that $f(c) - f(c+h)\leq \frac{1}{2} ( f(c-h) - f(c+h) ) \leq \frac{1}{4} ( f(c-3h) - f(c+h) ) \leq \dots \leq \frac{1}{2^n} ( f(c-(2^n -1)h) - f(c+h) ) \le \frac{M}{2^n}<\varepsilon $.
- The last two inequalities imply that $|f(x)- f(c)|< \varepsilon $ when $|x-c|< \delta $

---

### **My attempt**

To prove that  $  f(x)  $  is continuous at every point $  c \in (a,b)  $ , I need to show that for all  $  \varepsilon > 0  $ , there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that if $ |x - c| < \delta $, then $ |f(c) - f(x)| < \varepsilon $.

If $|x-c | < \delta$, then $x-\delta< c <x +\delta $
, $\exists  0<|h|< \delta $ such that we can write $ c+ h = x $. If I could prove that $|f(c) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$  or $|f(c+h) - f(c)| < \varepsilon  $  this will be enough to prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Since $f(x) $ is convex at $(a,b)$  (By definition) for $z,w \in (a,b) $  $f(tz +(1-t) w) < tf(z) +(1-t)f(w)$ in this formula I will put $z=c+2h , w = c$ and then use $t= \frac{1}{2}$  , to make sure that $c +2h \in (a,b )$ I will put this restrictions :  if $ c \in (a,b ) ,x\in (c-2\delta , c+ 2\delta)  $ and $(c- 2\delta , c+ 2\delta) \subset  (a+b )$    $$f(tz +(1-t) w) \leq tf(z) +(1-t)f(w)$$

$$f(c + 2t h) \leq f(c+ 2h )+ (1-t)f(c)$$
$$f(c + 2t h)- f(c) \leq t(f(c+ 2h )- f(c)  )  $$

$$f(c+h) - f(c) =f(x) - f(c)  \leq \frac{1}{2} (f(c+2h) - f(c) )$$

**First** to prove that the function is bounded on a closed interval

Let $ y >0 $ such that $[c-y , c+ y] \subset (a,b ) $.

If $x \in[c-y , c+ y] $ then $\exists t $ st $x = t(c-y) + (1-t) (c+y) $

$$|f(x)|= |f(t(c-y) + (1-t) (c+y) ) | \leq t|( f(c-y) - f(c+ y))| +|f(c+y)| $$ $$\leq 2(|f(c-y)|+|f(c+y)|) $$

The function is bounded on  $[c-y , c+ y] $.

$\\[4ex]$

**Secondly** to use the fact that $f $ is bounded in $[c-y , c+ y]$ to prove continuity of $f$.

Since the function is bounded  on $[c-y , c+ y]$  choose $M =2\sup\{|f(x) | \}  \forall x \in [c-y , c+ y] $.

Given $ \varepsilon >0 $ choose $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $  \frac{M}{2^n} < \varepsilon $ choose $\delta = \frac{y}{2^{n+1}}$

If  $k \leq n-1$ then since $f$ is convex the for  $z,w \in(a,b)$,  $f(tz +(1-t) w) \le tf(z) +(1-t)f(w)$ put $z = c+ 2^{k+1}h , w= c , t =\frac{1}{2}$. So  $f(c+2^{k}h  ) - f(c) \leq \frac{1}{2}(  f(c+2^{k+1}h  ) - f(c))$

So
$$f(c+h) - f(c) \le \frac{1}{2} (f(c+2h) - f(c) )\leq \frac{1}{4} (f(c+4h) - f(c) ) \leq \dots $$ $$\leq  \frac{1}{2^n} (f(c+2^nh) - f(c) )  \le \frac{M}{2^n}$$

Similarly one can prove this inequality ( the proof is analogous  to the last inequality.)   $$f(c) - f(c+h)\leq \frac{1}{2} ( f(c-h) - f(c+h) ) \leq \frac{1}{4} ( f(c-3h) - f(c+h) ) \leq \dots $$ $$\leq \frac{1}{2^n} ( f(c-(2^n -1)h) - f(c+h) ) \le \frac{M}{2^n}$$

then
$$ -\varepsilon< \frac{-M}{2^n}< f(c+h) - f(c) < \frac{M}{2^n}< \varepsilon$$
$$|f(c+h) - f(c)| < \frac{M}{2^n}< \varepsilon$$ this is true for any $ |h|< \delta$
$$|x-c|< \delta \text{ implies }|f(x)-f(c)|< \varepsilon $$
which mean that the function is continuous at $c$ and since $c$ is arbitrary then the function is continuous at $(a,b)$ .

---

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have **specific concerns** or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough

Comment: @MartinR I think my main Idea works but as I have been told my proof lacks some steps.

Comment: Hint for a simpler proof: convexity implies that slopes of secant lines increase as the x-coordinate of either endpoint is increased. This fact can be exploited to give upper and lower bounds for $(f(c + h) - f(c))/h$ for $h$ small. In other words, a suitable Lipschitz constant $K$ is obtained by taking the absolute value of one or the other bound, whichever is the greater in absolute value.

Comment: @user43208 I saw a similar proof with that idea. What about my proof? Is it corrects ?

Comment: It was hard to follow. But if your purported proof shows that the condition $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}$ implies continuity of $f$, then something is wrong because that is not true. Because, using the axiom of choice, one can show that there are $\mathbb{Q}$-linear maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that are not continuous, and $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity is a much stronger condition that $\frac1{2}$-convexity. Thanks for mentioning this by the way; it might help to locate an error in reasoning, if I have time to look more closely at it later. Or maybe someone else will.

Comment: (The proof of boundedness used more than $\frac1{2}$-convexity, so I think your proof is probably essentially sound, and you were right to remove that last sentence from a previous edit.)

Comment: @user43208 I added the "In summary " paragraph I hope it is clearer and much easier to follow and thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @user43208 I forgot about that part that uses more that $\frac 1 2 $ convexity

Comment: Imho the only thing you  will learn from making your life with that proof harder than necessary is what counter examples exist to the gaps in it. @user43208 has found one you should remember forever. To press on I strongly recommend that you look for the shortest possible, yet rigorous, proof of continuity for convex functions.

Comment: @KurtG. Somehow this proof is the first thing came to my mind and I didn't write it before posting it here , It was much shorter and easier in my head.

Comment: You should really put that condition $|h| < \delta = \frac{y}{2^{n+1}}$ *before* you embark on that long display line just after the word "So" (in the paragraph that begins "Secondly"), because only under that condition can you conclude with the bound $\frac{M}{2^n}$. I'll certify that the proof is basically correct, although I encourage you to keep improving it. However, the actual question as it is now seems based on a misunderstanding, because I did say in my previous comment that the proof looks essentially sound. The problem I mentioned earlier disappears if boundedness is established.